# Haar cascade traiing

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am training a haar cascade for american sign language.So I started by creating a sample haar cascade for the palm of my hand.However the train cascade returns HR=1 and FA=0 after stage 0 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCWbb.png).It gets stuck on training stage 1 pos count.Thanks in advance.

Comment: in the vec file must be more positive samples than the numPos parameter during training (about 10% more for standard parameters)

Comment: SAMPLES BAT FILE-opencv_createsamples.exe -info Positives.txt -vec samples1.vec -num 100 -w 50 -h 80 PAUSE

Comment: TRAIN BAT FILE-opencv_traincascade.exe -data classifier -vec samples1.vec -bg negatives.txt -numstages 1 -minhitrate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmrate 0.5 -numPos 50 -numNeg 100 -w 50 -h 80 -precalcvalBuffsize 1024 precalcdxbufsize 1024

Answer (score 0):

My first through is that you don't have enough positive or negative images.
How many positive and negative images do you provide for the training?
Can you give us what parameters you set for the training?

Comment: \opencv_traincascade.exe -data classifier -vec samples1.vec -bg negatives.txt -numstages 1 -minhitrate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmrate 0.5 -numPos 50 -numNeg 100 -w 50 -h 80 -precalcvalBuffsize 1024 precalcdxbufsize 1024

Comment: -numstages should not be 1. It's the numbers of stages, bigger it is, more accurate it is, slower it is. Try 20.

Comment: i tried with 5 but it gets stuck on training stage 1 POS count

Comment: in he traincascade file I gave num pos as 50 and num neg as 100

Comment: numPos and numNeg need to be lower than the number of image. Like Micka said, they should be around 10% of the number of real image. The explanation is that opencv_traincascade use this number to train each stage. So if it uses all images at the first stage, it have nothing for others.

Comment: If it's the problem, can you confirm? I will edit my answer.

Comment: there are formulas for numPos vs. actual number of positive samples. numNeg is hard to guess since automatic subsampling of full size negative samples provides quite a lot of negative samples, but on the other hand you'll need A LOT of negative samples during training (searching new negative samples typically is what makes cascade training so slow for higher stages)

Comment: opencv cretaesamples.exe creates 99 positive samples. I have changed the numpos to 10 but still there is no change in the outcome.

Comment: i have 800 in my negatives.txt

Comment: @P1t_  dude really need your help in this problem.

Comment: Found this http://answers.opencv.org/question/95147/opencv_traincascadeexe-crashes-while-at-neg-current-samples/
Maybe you should try on Linux machine.

Comment: i was hoping i could proceed on windows.

Comment: Try solutions from this link. If nothing work, you can train on Linux and make your program on Windows

Comment: @P1t_ will try that.I have asked another question.Look into it if u can please.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a python coder. If you solved this problem (run correctly opencv_traincascade on windows), can you come back for a feed back please